Who is "friend" here if Adam is Ashley's son?
After burning Fitz-Gibbonok to death, Adam was asked by his mother, Ashley,
to question Blurp, Fitz-Gibbonok’s pet:

Adam: He looks sad. I really don't enjoy how that's
making me feel, actually.

Then Ashley got annoyed

Master Karja (to Ashley): Your friend's a moron. I got one of those too.
I get it

Who is "friend" here if Adam is Ashley's son ?

It's Adam. There's no indication it would be anyone else.

@FuzzyBoots A son is not a friend. They are not on the same level.

Who is Ashley? Do you mean Ayesha?

Karja does not know their relationship. "Your friend" is a generic way to refer to someone's associate to whom you have not been introduced.

Quite frankly, there's no indication in the scene that it refers to anyone but Adam. It's possible that Karja does not realize that Adam is her son, as I don't see anything in the transcript where she refers to him as her son. It could also be that he's pre-extending his metaphor, that he was already planning to talk about his friend who is a moron, so he starts by referring to Adam as a "friend".

There's also the possibility that the person making the comment in the movie had no idea about their relationship, and was simply guessing they were friends.
